# how to make a functionality in a layout using laravel 5

Tags: php, forms, session-variables, laravel-5

Ok, so I have a partial contact form in the layout, and I'm trying to get the inputted data to pass to the full contact view form instead of submitting request via clicking the submit button.  In my partial, it has name, email, and phone input. I want the info to populate the appropriate input and the remaining inputs in the full contact form and the rest to be blank waiting for users to input them.  Then naturally on submit it sends out.  the full contact form is already working, I just need to get this partial on the layout to work. The problem is it's redirecting it to a view that's a get method.  I myself don't like this idea, but it's for my job and this is what they want.  I would preferr to not have to make another view.  This is what i have so far

the layout form:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'contact_index')) !!}

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('Name:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '', 'size' => '25']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('Email:') !!}
                    {!! Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '', 'size' => '25']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('Phone:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('phone', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '', 'size' => '25']) !!}
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="form_group">
                    {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

this is the controller it redirects to

```
  public function Index()
{
    $email  = Input::get('email');
    $name = Input::get('name');
    $phone = Input::get('phone');

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;

    return View('contact_views.Index',compact('email','name','phone'));
}
```

This is the view of the full contact:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'Contact')) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Email:') !!}
            {!! Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control',
            'placeholder' => '', value =>'$_SESSION['email']', size' => '25']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Name:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '',
            value =>'$_SESSION['name']', 'size' => '25']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Phone:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('phone', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '',
            value =>'$_SESSION['phone']', 'size' => '25']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Subject:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('subject', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '',
            value =>'', 'size' => '25']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Message:') !!}
            {!! Form::textarea('message', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '',
            value =>'', 'size' => '25x12']) !!}
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="form_group">
            {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

As of now this is the error I'm getting `FatalErrorException in b6da938076cfb151c583150cb7d0dec6 line 51:
syntax error, unexpected 'email' (T_STRING), expecting ']'` .

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra single quote on the line next to the "size" variable

```
   'placeholder' => '', value =>'$_SESSION['email']', size' => '25']) !!}
```